# Read from file to type

Tags: haskell

I am having problems reading from a file and loading it into a list of a type Film:

```
testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [(Film "Ridely Scott" "Test" 2012 [("Zoe",2),("Test",1)]),(Film "Test1" "Test1" 2012 [("Test",4),("Test",5)])]

loadFromFile :: IO ()
loadFromFile = do
         putStrLn "Enter the input filename: "
         name <- getLine
         contents <- readFile name
         let testDatabase = length contents `seq` (read contents :: [Film])
         putStrLn formatDatabase
         putStrLn "Done"
```

The text file has been saved by Haskell with the following method:

```
saveToFile :: IO ()
saveToFile = do
    putStrLn "Enter the output filename: "
    name <- getLine
    writeFile name (show testDatabase)
    putStrLn "Done"
```

It is in the correct format and it shows around 30 entries, but when the load method is called I get the data that was in testDatabase at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're from an imperative programming background, and new to functional programming. The thing to note: you *cannot* change the value of a variable. Ever.

Here, you simply create a new "variable" in the local scope of the `loadFromFile` function:

```
     let testDatabase = length contents `seq` (read contents :: [Film])
```

Which is then completely unknown to `formatDatabase` which must look somewhat like this:

```
formatDatabase :: String
formatDatabase = ... something with the global testDatabase ...
```

What you should do instead is have `formatDatabase` be a real function (rather than a constant `String`), and take the database as an argument:

```
formatDatabase :: [Film] -> String
formatDatabase database = ... something with database ...
```

And print it like this:

```
     let testDatabase = length contents `seq` (read contents :: [Film])
     putStrLn (formatDatabase testDatabase)
```

Comment: Say I want to load data at the start of the program, would everything have to be done on the fly with the information I load in? I can't load this into a global variable like ArrayList in Java or List in C#?

Comment: No, you cannot have global variables in Haskell that depend on impure data (from files etc.). It isn't good practice to do so in C#, and it isn't good practice to do so in Haskell.

Comment: I am talking about class variables, it isn't bad practice in C# :) I'll have to figure out a good way of working with imported data I guess.

Comment: @JamieB, you can have non-global mutable cells (`IORef`, `TVar`, etc), but reading/writing them needs to be done in a corresponding monad. You can even cheat around that by using unsafe tricks and make yourself a global variable, but you probably don't want to.